# angular doesn't apply changes to array(remove item on socket event)

Tags: angularjs, scope, apply, angularjs-ng-repeat, socket.io

First of all, sorry for my english, i'm ukrainian

When socketio card delete event performed, there is nothing changed in view

ng-repeat in my view

```
<card object="item" ng-repeat="item in LOG"></card>
```

In my controller

```
$scope.LOG = [{...},...{...}];
```

SocketIO emit

```
socket.on('card_was_deleted', function (data) {
    $scope.open_object = undefined;
    $scope.LOG = $scope.LOG.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.ID != data.id;
    });
});//or var index = ...;$scope.LOG.splice(index, 1);
```

I was looking for $scope.$apply() solutions and safe apply (while angular raise in progress exception), but nothing works.

help please.

wrapping this code into $apply raises "inprog" exception, because i have already

```
MyModule.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
var socket = io.connect(...);
var safeApply = function(scope, fn) {
  if (scope.$$phase) {
    fn();
  } else {
    scope.$apply(fn);
  }
};
return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function () {
            var args = arguments;
            safeApply($rootScope, function () {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
            });
        });
    },
    emit: .../*same code with eventData */
};
```

});

i found that replacing custom restricted element  with plain html  in ngRepeat works fine.
My directive

```
    .directive('card', function ($compile, $http, $templateCache) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '',
            scope: { object: '=',
                collapseClick: '&',
 ...
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var templateLoader = $http.get("/static/admin-panel/templates/card/card-" + (scope.object.type) + ".html", {cache: $templateCache});
                templateLoader.success(function (html) {
                    element.replaceWith($compile(html)(scope));
                });

            }}
    }
);
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap any angular related code which is not executed in normal angular flow with
`$scope.$apply` function, so it will look like:

```
socket.on('card_was_deleted', function (data) {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.open_object = undefined;
    $scope.LOG = $scope.LOG.filter(function (obj) {
       return obj.ID != data.id;
    });
  });
});
```

It will trigger internal angular event loop, you can read more about it [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).

Comment: thank you very much for your post. the problem was in another part of code, but i grateful to for your attempt