# setInterval function does not change the $scope in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a spring app with angular js and html in the client side, and I want to update the infromation in the view every 6 seconds for that i call setInterval function but it doesn't change the view
this is my code

```
$scope.aat=function(){
                $http.get("http://localhost:8080/projet/getInspectionEnCoursDinspection")
    .success(function (data) {

     $scope.tab1=data;
     console.log("size="+ $scope.inspectionEnCoursDinspection1.length);

   })   
} ,

setInterval(function(){ $scope.aat() },60000);
```

and this is my html view

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr ng-repeat="insp in tab1">
<td>Mat{{insp.vehicule.matricule}}

<div ng-repeat="aa in insp.tests">
Test<ul><li ng-repeat="defaut in aa.defauts">{{defaut.nomDefaut}}</li></ul>
</div>

</td>

<td><button ng-click="annulerTest()"
                                    class="btn btn-default btnt">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                                </button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

any help will be most appreciated

Comment: 60000ms is every minute, not every 6 seconds.

Comment: Try using ```$scope.apply``` to ```$scope.aat``` to tell Angular to register changes to your array.

Comment: ok thank u @Bergi but it's not the problem, the view doesn't change except that i refresh the page

Comment: ```$scope.aat=function(){
                $http.get("http://localhost:8080/projet/getInspectionEnCoursDinspection")
    .success(function (data) {

     $scope.tab1=data;
     console.log("size="+ $scope.inspectionEnCoursDinspection1.length);
$scope.apply();
   })   
}```

Comment: You should try using Angular's $interval instead of plainJS 'SetInterval'. Using any non-angular code to transform Angular stuff will de-sync your view unless you manually ```$scope.apply()```

Answer (score 3):

Related: [angular doesn't apply changes to array(remove item on socket event)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400000/angular-doesnt-apply-changes-to-arrayremove-item-on-socket-event)

This is because you're using setInterval to modify $scope.tab1 with $scope.aat.

Using any non-Angular code to modify your data will de-sync your view because Angular doesn't know about the change (it didn't do the work, so ofc it wouldn't know).

You could fix this either by using Angular's `$interval` instead of setInterval to repeat your updates. Or add `$scope.apply()` in `$scope.aat` to tell Angular to re-check everything for changes.

**It is better to use $interval in this case. $scope.apply() should be a last resort.**

```
$scope.aat=function(){
                $http.get("http://localhost:8080/projet/getInspectionEnCoursDinspection")
    .success(function (data) {

     $scope.tab1=data;
     console.log("size="+ $scope.inspectionEnCoursDinspection1.length);
     //this--->$scope.apply();
   })   
} ,

//OR this-->$interval(function(){ $scope.aat() },60000);
```

Comment: $interval... I try to only use .apply() when there is no angular alternative.

Comment: @Tyler Agreed, just letting OP know his or her options

Comment: Cheers. The explanation of .apply() is useful for other instances where a built-in isn't possible.